# How to infer class properties type without extending the class

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-generics

```
class XClass {
x = "x";
y = 11;
b = true;
}
let xObj = new XClass();
function getSchema<T extends XClass>(instance: T): Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]> {
const returnObj = {} as Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]>;
for (const key in instance) {
  returnObj[key] = instance[key]; // Direct assignment infers correct types
}
return returnObj;
}
let schema = getSchema(xObj);
type X = typeof schema;


/* type being inferred as 
type X = {
x: string | number | boolean;
y: string | number | boolean;
b: string | number | boolean;
}

// It should be instead :
type X = {
x: string;
y: number;
b: boolean;
}
*/
```

Typescript is  inferring the types as a union.
When i want to infer type of class properties each key is being inferred as all the possible types of the class properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following mapped type:

```ts
type ClassProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}
```

Full code:

```ts
class XClass {
  x = "x";
  y = 11;
  b = true;
}

type ClassProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}

function getSchema<T extends XClass>(instance: T): ClassProps<T> {
  const returnObj = {} as ClassProps<T>;
  for (const key in instance) {
    returnObj[key] = instance[key];
  }
  return returnObj;
}

const xObj = new XClass();
const schema = getSchema(xObj);
type X = typeof schema;
// type X = {
//   x: string;
//   y: number;
//   b: boolean;
// }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAaDC4rQN4ChrQB7QLzQCIsCBuDaATz2gEYazMAjagFwCcBXAUzIF800LCgAcu0RJAgAFNgHthEADwAVAHzV0mANoBpaAEsAdtADWXCrIBm0ZQF0AXDd220-NJY6HgLfbOMBzLhYAZWAACy4AWzAVaC4sFi5DABMYBCQIVQAKIwgWMC8uR2UASkcJKBl5JTVUcmA-POg2II42QwB5RgArDV5oSHEMqoUVVQZoS1k2aCyGwyazKiMDBfzCkrrMTBaWNs6erSXbalz14C4j81sJ-h3W9uaHg+6+AXmmrC7e-EMuAHc4BUIFkSmQPixoBBwlEwNRAiEYdEsl8emDBCIxLBWJirFCkWAyAB6InbAB6AH40EA)